# Disabling dates in an ExtJS calendar

Tags: extjs

I want to disable certain dates in my calendar. I have code to do this, but in this code the dates are statically loaded. I need to retrieve the list of dates from my database.

I know how to retrieve the data from my database, but I don't know how to pass it from the store to the view array. Can anyone help me to resolve it?

```
dateArray = ["06/17/2007","06/01/2007","05/17/2007","05/01/2007"];

dateField = new Ext.form.DateField({
            format:"m/d/Y",
            disabledDates:["^("+dateArray.join("|")+").*$"],
            disabledDatesText:"Date not available."
});
```

Comment: The most straightforward is to make a reference to your view or store available in the closure of your request callback. It may be cleaner to fire a custom event from the callback, and react to it somewhere in a controller, to update the view. Hard to illustrate without knowing your request and view code.

Answer (score 0):

`disabledDates` config option accepts arrays of dates, so if you are saying you have the store handy, you can simply do something like:

```
var disabledDates = [];
store.each(function(record){
    disabledDates.push(record.get('putYourDateFieldNameHere'));
});
dateField = new Ext.form.DateField({
            format:"m/d/Y",
            disabledDates: disabledDates,
            disabledDatesText:"Date not available."
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
var disabledDates = [];
store.each(function(record){
    disabledDates.push(record.get('putYourDateFieldNameHere'));
});
dateField = new Ext.form.DateField({
            format:"m/d/Y",
            disabledDatesText:"Date not available."
});
dateField.setDisabledDates(disabledDates);
```